# Will the electron in a circuit without a load gain ever more potential energy every time it passes through a battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, potential-energy, voltage, batteries

Say we have a circuit without any load, just a wire and a 1.5 V battery, so there is no full potential drop as it gets to opposite terminal. Will there be 1.5 V of potential added every time it passes through a battery, and  will repeating this cycle give electron ever more potential energy, with each passing through battery?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a real-world answer, the battery has an internal resistance.  Even with no load, the battery can't push much current before the resistance equals the voltage.  The charge is dropping the energy within the battery (causing it to heat up).

If you had an ideal voltage source with no resistance, then the current would keep increasing until either the small resistance of the wire added up to 1.5V, or until the wire started melting due to all the power flowing through it.

If you had and ideal voltage source and a zero-resistance circuit, then there is no steady-state solution.  The current would increase over time without limit (because the ideal voltage source has no limits on power it can generate).

Answer (score 1):

(a) I assume that you mean that the wire (of negligible resistance) is connected straight across the battery terminals. In other words you are short-circuiting the battery. I'd reserve the expression 'no load' for when there is *nothing* connected across the terminals, that is the battery is 'open circuit'. [Although a wire of zero resistance can't itself dissipate energy, it does allow a current through itself, and therefore through the battery. It would be, at the very least, *controversial* to say that it isn't a load.]

(b) By definition you can't have increasing potentials at the same point each time an electron passes the point. The potential of a point is the same no matter by what route we reach the point.

(c) What happens is that the electron (or whatever charge carrier it may be) has work done on it through chemical reactions as it passes on and off the electrodes in the battery. You can indeed say that the potential energy of the carrier is increased in the process. But as it passes through the bulk of the electrolyte, it does work against resistive forces – we talk about the internal resistance of the cell – and loses energy. [If you don't short-circuit the cell with your wire of negligible resistance, it will also do work against resistive forces in the external circuit (the load).] When it has returned to its starting point it will have lost whatever potential energy it acquired; the energy will have been released as internal (thermal) energy in the cell, and thence given out as heat to the surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

Even with no load, an electron loses all of its potential when it reaches the other terminal.